# Can't install extensions? Connect 404

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions

I've been having the problem for about a week and I cannot find a work around. I can't seem to install extensions at all.

I am using Magento 1.9.0.1 and when I go to Magento connect I get a 404 error. I have tried CHMOD downloader & downloader/index.php to 644 but still get 404.

Is there a workaround or a way to manually install extensions? When I have tried via FTP it tries to overwrite existing files which it shouldn't.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please check something

1. Check your source have folder downloader
2. Check .htaccess have permission access folder
3. chmod folder downloader 775

Answer (score 0):

Consider setting permissions for your downloader path to 0755 and run the magento cleaner.

1. Download http://www.techjam.gr/techjamwp/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/magento-cleanup.zip
2. Extract and upload cleaner file to your magento root directory
3. Run the cleaner by navigating to: https://yoursite.com/magento-cleaner.php

After you complete these steps the Magento Connect Manager should function properly.